# Sending Http requests from Xamarin Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, http, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I have quite decent problems with this very simple task and asking for help.
The question is: what is the best and the most reliable way to perform Http requests with timeout from Xamarin PCL?

There are several options:

1. Using old HttpWebRequest. This solution should definitely be working, but I have problems with BeginGetRequestStream method described in this question: [HttpWebRequest BeginGetRequestStream callback never called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22572084/1645784) Also it requres some extra ugly code to implement timeouts properly.
2. HttpClient. HttpClient is not available in PCL out-of-the-box (I am using Profile 158 required by MvvmCross libraries). I was trying to install Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries but I still cannot compile the PCL project, error is:

   > The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
3. PortableRest NuGet package. Same problem - does not seem to work in PCL. Lots of compilation errors and warnings, for example:

   > The primary reference "System.Net.Http" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile158". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Net.Http" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=1.5.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". (MSB3268) (Prototype.Core)

What am I doing wrong? Why am I not able to use such basic standard libraries?

**UPDATE**

Finally solved the issue by switching to Profile 78 (.NET 4.5). Now I can use HttpClient which is way better and easy to use. It works reliably with all my requests. MvvmCross libraries work fine with Profile 78 as well.

The only issue I have is lack of Timer class. Maybe I should implement it myself using Task.Delay.

Comment: On `HttpWebRequest` I believe your only problem is with `Timeout` - I believe this was omitted from the Compact Framework and so is not available in WP or in the PCLs. The reason for this omission is the word **compact** - they had to leave some things out in order to make the compact framework fit inside smaller memory spaces. The MvvmCross network plugin uses HttpWebRequest and I've never had any `never called back` type problems with it - but it does not support `Timeout` directly - I find this can be worked around using some simple, clean `Timer` and `Abort` code.

Comment: If you plan on using HttpClient cross-platform, check out this post by James Montemagno: http://motzcod.es/post/78863496592/portable-class-libraries-httpclient-so-happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using the HttpClient package via NuGet http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

This works with profile 78 and MvvmCross. You also get async/await support.

Comment: I've used this in 158 too - e.g. in the video of http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/quick-run-through-using-pcls-in.html

Comment: I originally went that route but there were too many issues getting the HttpClient to work on Android. I ultimately went with an abstracted IRestClient interface and dependency injection. This also made it very easy to use ModernHttpClient on Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

What about HttpClient, I've extended Profile 7, so it now supports WP7/8, iOS, Android and WinStore and it works great, no problem yes and I've already complete a couple of projects with it.

Comment: Do you use MvvmCross?

Comment: As I understand I am forced to use 158'th profile since I use mvvmcross libraries (which are great).

Comment: The latest versions of  Xamarin support profile 78. And yes you can use MvvmCross with this profile.

Comment: @Alex Petrenko Yes I'm and I also extend profile 7, to add Win7 to the list of platforms, just forget to add it.